# How to include WordPress Advance Custom Field plugin functions in single PHP file?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to get value from WordPress post custom field (with WordPress Advance Custom Field plugin) and echoing this the custom field value on a single (standalone) PHP file on WordPress root directory with this PHP code

```
<?php
    require_once("wp-load.php");

    $value = get_field( "content" );

    echo $value;

?>
```

and it doesn't work, what is the correct method to include the WordPress functions?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `the_field()` function

```
<?php
$parse_uri = explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );
require_once( $parse_uri[0] . 'wp-load.php' );

$page_id=123;
the_field('content',$page_id);

 ?>
```

Comment: the problem is this standalone php file, how to call this function on a standalone php file

Comment: the_filed used page id

Comment: it can't the php file will get value from random page/post, and also the question is how to call this function from standalone php file on wordpress root directory not on plugin directory

Comment: already tried and get this error message on my nginx --> log PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '../../../wp-load.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php')

Answer (score 0):

Remove require_once("wp-load.php"); from your code and add following code for Retrieving a field as a variable.

```
<?php

$variable = get_field('field_name');

// do something with $variable

echo $variable;

?>
```

Hope this will help. Please let me know if any issue.

Comment: this is standalone php file on wordpress root directory not on plugin directory, thanks

Comment: where is your file placed let me know

Comment: wordpress root folder along with wp-config.php and wp-load.php

Comment: Are you editing wordpress core file?That is not good method if you updating the wordpress then all changes are you made will be lost.

Comment: im not editing wordpress core, i create my own php file and add it on wordpress root dir to get this custom field value

Comment: what is the need of that file in root directory??

Answer (score 0):

Custom field is related with specific posts, pages, custom post type so when you want to retrieve filed value then you must pass **ID** , at root file by default it will not have any POST ID.

So your code will work in this way

```
<?php
      require_once("wp-load.php");
      $value = get_field( "content", $ID ); // $ID = specific post, page id
      echo $value;

 ?>
```

This code is worked for me, I hope its work for you as well.